# This jquery file contains code to detect certain features in minecraft terrain. How do I extract a specific part of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minecraft

I'm using this site: https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/seed-map#-414408884134053378

It's the only code I've found publicly that can detect a specific minecraft feature ("caves, "cheese caves")

My goal is to do one of the following:

1. Preferably, determine how they're determining where the caves are and be able to reuse/reverse engineer this code (for my own private use). I've gotten as far as locating cb3-finder.c9723522.js. Within that file, I find this:

`g[CB3Libs.POI.Cave] = { gaId: "Ca", imgSrc: "cave.png", dimension: CB3Libs.Dimension.Overworld, maxTileSize: f.veryBig, splitPois: b, _getSize: function(a) { return a.count < 600 ? "small" : a.count < 1800 ? "medium" : "large" }, getCoords: function(a) { return a[2].reference.pos }, getTooltipText: function(a) { a[2].count; return "Cheese Cave (" + g[CB3Libs.POI.Cave]._getSize(a[2]) + ")" }, fillColor: function() { return "68,68,68" }`

But I'm not really seeing where the algorithm to determine where the caves are. Yet I'm not finding other code referring to the caves, so I'm pretty confused.

2. Since it seems like I might be in over my head here, I instead wanted to at least try editing the js to only show caves over a certain threshold (say, 10,000). I can't really figure out how to do this either. I edited the

`return a.count < 600 ? "small" : a.count < 1800 ? "medium" : "large"`

line to a variety of different things (ie, returning just "" when it's small or medium, then changing the threshold for medium/large), but this doesn't do anything beyond having the caves show up on the page, but with no text where it'd normally say their size. Which makes sense, but I'm not really seeing where/how I could short cut it to not display anything if they're medium/small.

I did figure out one change which was helpful, which was to return a.count instead of a readout of their "size category" which allows me to at least load the page and manually click around and see what the size of the caves are. Which is an improvement! but still not really what I'm going for.

Any help with either problem would be appreciated!

I tried searching through the code to extract or change things. I managed to change some functionality but not in the way I was hoping to (see above)

Comment: I was trying something silimar. The terrain generation logic is within a Rust program compiled into a WebAssembly, and loaded into a Worker. Look for inlineWorker* in that JS file, and you'll find a long string which is a JS wrapper of a base64 encoded WebAssembly program. I've gotten as far as: myworker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(inlineWorker_k9bk8)); myworker.addEventListener("message", function(a) { console.log(JSON.stringify(a.data)); }  myworker.postMessage({ type: "check", tile: { ... }, params: { ... }. Running out of space for a comment, so fill in ...'s. :)

Comment: I found another tool to find minecraft features, check out cubiomes-viewer.